# Chrome extension issue: Dictionary keys must be quoted

Tags: json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Trying to make my first Chrome extension and getting the follow error: Manifest is not valid JSON. Line:2, column:4, Dictionary keys must be quoted. Here's my Manifest.JSON:

```
{
  “manifest_version”: 2,
  "name": "James Hipstour",
  "description": "Replace all mentions of 'hipster' with James Montour.",
  "version": "1.0”,
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://jquery.com/*"],
      "js": ["jquery-2.1.1.js", "content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "background_page": "background.html"
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: SO's syntax highlighting should have been a clue: `“manifest_version”` was not highlighted as a string.

Answer (score 16):

```
“manifest_version”: 2,
...
"version": "1.0”,
```

Those `“`smart`”` quotes need to be changed to `"`plain`"` ones.

```
"manifest_version": 2,
...
"version": "1.0",
```

See the difference?

When you edit code, make sure you do it in a plain text editor like Notepad. Stay away from word processors like Word.

Answer (score 0):

This happened for me when I specified an invalid script for the `background:scripts` key.

By correcting the path, the issue was resolved.